# Has anyone discovered a fix for the Asus Zenbook screen problems?

Tags: suspend, brightness, asus

The Ubuntu help wiki for the Asus Zenbook says that "waking from suspend does not work (screen stays black, with no way to turn it back on) and setting the brightness of the screen is not possible through the gnome-settings or xbacklight/xrandr."
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AsusZenbookPrime

Has anyone figured out a solution to this? I'm on a UX-32A, and stuck on max brightness and can't wake the thing up from suspend. I really need help.

Answer (score 1):

The problem has been fixed in kernel 3.7.x+ upgrading to 13.04 solves this problem.